# Filter by date: Before today + 2days

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a table of information and each row has a date in column A.

How can I filter the table to only show everything before today + 2 days (workdays)?

- The table headers are on row 11 and the data begins on row 12
- I have =Today() in cell D2

```
Sub Datefilter()

Dim MyVal As Date
Dim ORTable As ListObject

MyVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Range("D2").Value, 2)
Worksheets("Open Report").Range(A12 - A9999).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=<" & MyVal

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: `A12 - A9999` should be `"A12:A9999"`.

Comment: @BigBen when I do that I get a Compile Error "Expected: List separator or )"

Comment: the compile error is because you don't have " marks. It should read ```Worksheets("Open Report").Range("A12:A9999").AutoFilter...```

Comment: @ChrisH. Thank you for the tips. I made the chances and now have the "AutoFilter method of Range class failed" error for the following: ```Sheets("Open Report").Range("A12:A9999").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=<" & MyVal```

Comment: This works....```MyVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Range("D2").Value, -2)
Worksheets("Open Report").Range("A11:A9999").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=" & MyVal```

Comment: I changed the range to ```("A11:Q11")``` and I didn't receive any error messages, but it filtered every date in my table so that it was left blank. Any suggestions on how to fix this??